# How to pass a cloned parameter by spread syntax in TS?

Tags: typescript

here's my code.

```
interface myObj {
  name?: string,
  age?: number,
  address?: string
}

const obj1: myObj = { age: 12 }
const obj2 = { name: 'jack' }
const obj3: myObj = { ...obj1, ...obj2 }

const printOut = (msg: string): void => {
  console.log(msg)
}

printOut(obj3.name)
```

I got an error message

`TS2345: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

on line
`printOut(obj3.name)`

Appreciate for the help!

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

As the error is trying to tell you, `.name` on `myObj` might be `undefined`, so you cannot pass it as `string`.

You can remove `: myObj` from the declaration to let the compiler infer the type of the variable, in which case it will infer (because of the type `obj2`) that `name` is `string`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! Basically, remove the question mark behind the `name` key. Since I am using this `name` key, so it shouldn't be a `maybe` type.